# How can i like my facebook profile picture with likeView

Tags: android

I want to offer every body to like my profile pic in my app with LikeView button provided by facebook sdk. what type of link i need to use.->

```
val photoLikeButton = findViewById<LikeView>(R.id.likeViewID)
            photoLikeButton.setObjectIdAndType("", LikeView.ObjectType.UNKNOWN)
```

Comment: Hi, I think you've posted this question in the wrong place. I assume you want StackOverflow or one of the other programming Stacks. I've flagged your post for attention by a moderator to be migrated.

Comment: @adaliabooks Well done. Best to get the OP to the right place.